# How to find the determinant of a 5x5 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How do I find the determinant of this?
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0& 6& −2& −1& 5\\
0& 0& 0& −9& −7\\
0& 15& 35& 0& 0\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried doing row reductions but every time I get a $0$ and I gain a number. I'm not really sure how to do this by cofactors

Comment: Is your issue is that it's taking too long?  (Not an unreasonable objection.)  Have you tried expanding down the first column?  That reduces it to a $4 \times 4$ right away.

Answer (score 2):

By using a Laplace expansion along the first column the problem immediately boils down to computing $R=-2\cdot\det(M)$ with
$$ \det M=\det\begin{pmatrix}6&-2&-1& 5 \\ 0 & 0 & -9 & -7 \\ 15 & 35 & 0 & 0 \\ -1&-11&-2&1\end{pmatrix}=-5\cdot\det\begin{pmatrix}6&-2&1& 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 9 & -7 \\ 3 & 7 & 0 & 0 \\ -1&-11&2&1\end{pmatrix}$$
hence
$$ R = 10\left[-9\det\begin{pmatrix}6&-2& 5 \\ 3 & 7  & 0 \\ -1&-11&1\end{pmatrix}-7\det\begin{pmatrix}6&-2&1 \\ 3 & 7 & 0  \\ -1&-11&2\end{pmatrix}\right]$$
$$ R = 10\left[-9\det\begin{pmatrix}11&53& 0 \\ 3 & 7  & 0 \\ -1&-11&1\end{pmatrix}-7\det\begin{pmatrix}6&-2&1 \\ 3 & 7 & 0  \\ -13&-7&0\end{pmatrix}\right]$$
$$ R = 10\left[-9\cdot(11\cdot 7-53\cdot 3)-7\cdot\left(-7\cdot 3+7\cdot 13\right)\right]=\color{red}{2480}.$$

Comment: @Bernard: sure, fixed.

Comment: @jack-daurizio : what do you think about the method proposed by Gjonbalaj and Salihu, concerning the "cornice determinants"? [http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/AMEN/2010/090802-1.pdf] [1]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it purely by row reduction:

First add 6 times the fourth row to the first one, we get
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
0& 6& −2& −1& 5\\
0& 0& 0& −9& −7\\
0& 15& 35& 0& 0\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
0& 0& −68& −13& 11\\
0& 0& 0& −9& −7\\
0& 15& 35& 0& 0\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align}
Now add 15 times the fourth row to the third one:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0& 0& −68& −13& 11\\
0& 0& 0& −9& −7\\
0& 0& -130& -30& 15\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Now multiply the first row by 65 and the third one by 34 (of, course, factoring those number out as divisors:
$$
\frac1{34\times65}\,\begin{vmatrix}
0& 0& -4420& -845& 715\\
0& 0& 0& −9& −7\\
0& 0& -4420& -1020& 510\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Now subtract the third row from the first one:
$$
\frac1{34\times65}\,\begin{vmatrix}
0& 0& 0& 175& 205\\
0& 0& 0& −9& −7\\
0& 0& -4420& -1020& 510\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Now multiply the first row by 9 and the second one by 175:
$$\frac1{9\times34\times65\times175}\,\begin{vmatrix}
0& 0& 0& 1575& 1845\\
0& 0& 0& −1575& −1225\\
0& 0& -4420& -1020& 510\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}
$$
and then add the second row to the first one:
$$
\frac1{9\times34\times65\times175}\,\begin{vmatrix}
0& 0& 0& 0& 620\\
0& 0& 0& −1575& −12255\\
0& 0& -4420& -1020& 510\\
0 &−1 &−11& −2& 1\\
−2 &−2& 3& 0& −2\end{vmatrix}
$$

The determinant is then 
$$
\frac{(-2)\times1\times (-4420)\times1575\times620}{9\times34\times65\times175}=2480.
$$

Comment: Please explain that the antidiagonal permutation that survives is even so you do not need a minus sign before the product.

Comment: The way I see it is that I calculate each minor along the first column. So $-1$ and $-9$ carry a minus sign each, that cancel each other.